# Sort List of Strings by having a character Flutter

Tags: string, flutter, list, dart, sorting

I have a List of strings ["pana", "open","peno","alp","palp"]

and i need to sort them by having the letter "p", then alphabetically:

so the result should be ["pana", "palp","peno", "open","alp"]

How can i do this in Flutter

Comment: all items will start from `p`?

Comment: @MunsifAli it might start with any letter

Comment: os if it has ["abc","pa","pb","bc"]. you want it to sort like this ? ["pa","pb","abc","bc"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a roundabout way of doing it but:

```
  var list = [
    "pana",
    "open",
    "peno",
    "alp",
    "palp",
    "kk",
    "can",
    "aaa",
    "111"
    ,"zs",
    "sz",
  ];
  
  var pattern = 'p';
  
  var listStartsWith = list.where((word) => word.startsWith(pattern)).toList()
    ..sort((a, b) => a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase()));

  var listContains = list
      .where((word) => word.contains(pattern) && !word.startsWith(pattern))
      .toList()
    ..sort((a, b) => a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase()));
  
    var listContainsNot = list
      .where((word) => !word.contains(pattern) && !word.startsWith(pattern))
      .toList()
    ..sort((a, b) => a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase()));

  var reoderedList = [...listStartsWith, ...listContains, ...listContainsNot];
  
  print(reoderedList);
```

I will update once I've been able to optimise it but we can work off this for now.